# How can I programatically change a jQuery select2 item?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, combobox, jquery-select2

I have a dropdown on an `asp.net-mvc` page:

```
<% = Html.DropDownList("PersonId", Model.DevManagers, 
  new { @id = "PersonId", @class = "searchDropdown" })%>
```

and I am converting it to use jQuery `select2` like this

```
$(".searchDropdown").select2({
  width: "500px",
  allowClear: true
});
```

the issue is that if I try then changing the underlying `select` value like this:

```
$('#PersonId').val(data.TechOwnerId);
```

the `select2` widget doesn't change the `selecteditem`

What is the correct way to update the jQuery `select2` selected item programmatically?

Comment: data is a javascript object coming back from a Ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this -

```
$('#PersonId').select2("val",data.TechOwnerId);
```

Have a look at the API `-->`  http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/   <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> `.select2("val"`

Comment: how to make buttons lke you made ctrl + f?? its silly question but i don't lnow

Comment: @EhsanSajjad click on edit under my answer, You will get your answer `:)`

Comment: Ohh... ok. let me check

Comment: there are more short keys as well to make post more readable, where i can see all??